# How to make a Javascript code refer to the same attribue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The following is a Javascript code segment of an AngularJS code:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
       .state('lodge', {
    ...
       }
        .state('lodge.new', {
            parent: 'lodge',
            url: '/new',
            data: {
                roles: ['ROLE_USER'],
            },
            onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$modal', function($stateParams, $state, $modal) {
                $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'scripts/app/entities/lodge/lodge-dialog.html',
                    controller: 'LodgeDialogController',
                    size: 'lg',
                    resolve: {
                        entity: function () {
                          var price = {currency: null, value: 0};
                          return {id: null, description: null, transportationHourlyRate: price, houseCleaningHourlyRate: price);
                      }
                    }
                }).result.then(function(result) {
                    $state.go('lodge', null, { reload: true });
                }, function() {
                    $state.go('lodge');
                })
            }]
        })
   .state('lodgeXXX', {
    ...
       }
  ...
```

On the html page where the above code is used, the price will be the same for both rates based on a user lasted enter data. If I only want the currency to be the same, but not the value, how the code shall be modified? I have tried a few approaches something like the followings without a luck.

```
var currency_var = {currency: null};
var price1 = {currency: currency_var, value: 0},  price2 = {currency: currency_var, value: 0};
return {id: null, description: null, transportationHourlyRate: price1, houseCleaningHourlyRate: price2);
```

The html side code is something like the followings:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label translate="myApp.lodge.transportationHourlyRate.currency" for="field_transportationHourlyRate_currency">TransportationHourlyRateCurrency</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="transportationHourlyRate.currency" ng-model="lodge.transportationHourlyRate.currency" id="field_transportationHourlyRate_currency">
            <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
            <option value="USD">USD</option>
        </select>

        <div ng-show="editForm.transportationHourlyRate.currency.$invalid">
            <p class="help-block"
               ng-show="editForm.transportationHourlyRate.currency.$error.required" translate="entity.validation.required">
                This field is required.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label translate="myApp.lodge.transportationHourlyRate.value" for="field_transportationHourlyRate_value">TransportationHourlyRateCurrency</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="transportationHourlyRate.value" ng-model="lodge.transportationHourlyRate.value" id="field_transportationHourlyRate_value">
        </input>
    </div>
```

The html code structure is the same for houseCleaningHourlyRate.

Comment: In your `price2` object, `currency_var` is misspelt as `currencey_var`

Answer (score 0):

Your example is close, but instead of assigning an Object value to `currency_var`, you simply want:

```
var currency_var = null;
```

Then you can use that variable to apply the same value to your price variables' `currency` key. I'm not sure how that factors into your Angular app without seeing more code, though.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I actually have tried setting without luck.

Comment: Then more information is needed, or your question is malformed.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the problem by checking the values, when you do:

```
var currency_var = {currency: null}
```

You are creating an object with a property `currency`, so the object itself is not null. If you check `typeof(currency_var)` you will get `object` instead of `null` as you would expect.

Just change:

```
var price1 = {currency: currency_var, value: 0}, ...
```

for:

```
var price1 = {currency: currency_var.currency, value: 0}, ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have tested out your suggestion. It doesn't yield to the desired result.

Comment: @vic: Well, that is the problem with that piece of code, you will have to give us more information ;)

Comment: Thanks both. I just add more related code in my original post. Please let me know if more code is needed to solve this problem.

Comment: @vic: Check that in price2, you have `price2 = {currency: currencey_var`, should be `currency_var`, is misspelt

Comment: Sorry for the typo. It is only on this post. My code is correct. I just have a double check. The Intellij Idea gives me a good tool to check the variable name correction. I will make a correction on my original post.